# C++ Using (communications) object in every other class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've recently made an "communications" object/abstract class, on which I can use the functions:
"send", "receive", "debugsend" etc.

Now, I'd like to use this object in basically every other class, so that I can use it to send debug messages.

At the moment I'll have to do:

```
#include "../communication/ICommunication.hpp"
extern Communication* comm;
```

In any of the other files/classes where I want to use this object.
While this seems to work very well, I was wondering if there is a neater way to do this.

I believe there is an software pattern for this, though I can't remember the name, nor the implementation. The name of the pattern was, I believe, a persons last name.

I'd like to know the name of this pattern (or any pattern that's good for this purpose), so I could try the implementation myself. 
If possible, also some arguments on why that pattern is better than the "include and extern" code.

Comment: For starters, you could declare the `extern` inside the header. Whether it is a good idea to have this global in the first place, is hard to tell from here.

Comment: @Thomas d'oh, that makes sense indeed. And it was in global of my main (and I want to use it globally, or well at least when I include "ICommunication"), so I think your point is very valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern you tak about is called singleton (and is often called an antipattern). It should looks as follows:

```
struct MySingleton {
static MySingleton& getInstance() {
   static MySingleton singleton;
   return singleton;
}
};
```

better aproach would be to pass `Communication` instance to each of you class as a parameter to constructor. You could also wrap it into `shared_ptr` so that once all the classes will no longer refer to it, destructor of Communication object will automatically be called.

> if possible, also some arguments on why that pattern is better than the "include and extern" code.

I think one issue you may encounter is how your Communication object lifetime is managed. It should be created before first use, and I suppose it should be destroyed after any other class or function might want to use it.

I am not sure if singleton is good for Communication object, I assume you use it to make a connection with server and after a while you Disconnect. This can be done with Sigleton, but from my experience Singletons are used more for objects which lifetime is a lot longer, like for the whole duration of application.

Comment: Yup, I was looking for the "Singleton" pattern. It will be used within an Embedded project, where this object will (hopefully) live forever ;).

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know the name of this pattern (or any pattern that's good for this purpose), so I could try the implementation myself. If possible, also some arguments on why that pattern is better than the "include and extern" code.

The best practices to use at the moment, are interface abstraction and dependency injection:

First abstract the operations you are going to use on your comm object:

```
struct Communicator
{
    virtual void send(const std::string&) = 0;
    virtual std::string receive() = 0;
    // etc
};

// injectable Communicator implementation that does nothing; this is useful as
// a default argument for code that uses communicators: it will show the dependency 
// explicitly, but setting it as a default argument ensures that client code
// doesn't _have to_ use a communicator, if you don't have one available
struct NoOpCommunicator: Communicator
{
    void send(const std::string&) override {}
    std::string receive() override { return {}; }
} dummy_communicator; // <--- notice this global
```

Client code:

```
class YourClientCode // (uses a Communicator)
{
public:
    YourClientCode(Communicator& c = dummy_communicator) // communicator instance,
                                                         // dependency injected here
    : com(c)
    {   
    }
private:
    void f() { com.send("f()"); /* ... */ }

    Communicator& com;
};

auto client1 = YourClientCode{};
auto client2 = YourClientCode{ GetActualCommunicatorReference() };
```

This is better than include + extern, because it doesn't hardcode the dependency on the communicator, and doesn't impose that in order to use client code you *MUST* have a communicator up and running. This improves testability and reusability of your code drastically.

Comment: Hmm, this is also a very interesting answer, though, I do have some degree of abstraction built into the communications object already. I can use the Communications class with a Serial implementation (or for example USB or Ethernet, but also a NoOp one). But I agree it's a fancy and good way of doing it.